# How add radius to top and bottom on ContstraintLayout on Android 4.3?

Tags: android

Android 4.3. 
Here my xml layuout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like_inactive"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewDownload"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewPhoto" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDownload"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/subTitleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_download_inactive" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result:

[image: container]

I want to add radius corner on top and bottom on Android 4.3. How I can do this? As you can see on top has **imageView** and on bottom has **textView**.

Maybe use drawable?

P.S. **CardView** not help because it not work on Android 4.3.

Comment: why are you not use cardview ? look how many device are run on 4.3 or below
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: It's client requirement. Start app on Android 4.0+

Comment: then show you client this url and convince them , otherwise  you lost most off new feature in app, to support older version.

Comment: I'm not sure that client change it's mind.